# Does Illustrator CSS Extraction work on psd files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, css, mockup

I have a .psd web design mockup I'd like to bring from Photoshop into Illustrator CC and use the CSS Extraction functionality on. Is this possible, or must the file have been created in Illustrator and saved as an Illustrator file?

Currently I can't test this because my Illustrator CC trial is expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. At least to a degree.

The .psd....

[image]

Saved and *opened* with Illustrator CC2017 choosing to `Convert layers to Objects`. Then selected all and clicked the Generate CSS....

[image]